# ¿Cómo se diría "vegetariano" en español si no nos hubiera llegado el término del inglés?

Tags: etimología, solicitud-de-término

Leo en el DLE que la palabra *[vegetariano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bRCXZBr)* proviene directamente del inglés *vegetarian*, palabra inventada a partir de *vegetable*. No encuentro en el DLE que la palabra pudiera ser una composición en español de *vegetal* (o *verdura*, en realidad) y algún sufijo, dado que *-ariano* no existe como tal en nuestro idioma.

Lo curioso es que veo que a partir de esta palabra y otras como *frutariano*, se ha sacado la sílaba *ta* como factor común y están apareciendo nombres para los que practican las [variantes relajadas del vegetarianismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semivegetarianismo), tales como *pescetariano* y *pollotariano* (que admiten pequeñas cantidades de carne de pescado o de pollo, respectivamente). Puede que algún día la RAE admita *-tariano* como elemento compositivo, quién sabe.

Así que se ocurre un nuevo juego etimológico y os propongo: ¿cuál habría sido la palabra usada en español para *vegetarianismo* si esta se hubiera creado directamente en español? Se me ocurren cosas como *vegetalario* o *verdulario* usando *[-ario](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3YvWLaw)* como en *boticario* (aunque significa "profesión" y no "persona") o tal vez *verdulero*, con *[-ero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G2rZOMn)* como en *ingeniero*, pero nuevamente significa "profesión" (de hecho un *verdulero* es el que vende verduras). ¡Participen y expliquen sus propuestas!

Bonus: ¿Se usaba alguna palabra en español para este concepto antes de la llegada de *vegetariano*? ¿O eso de comer solo verdura era algo inconcebible para los hablantes del español?

Answer (score 8):

Un sufijo útil en este caso podría ser "‒́voro".

> [**‒́voro**](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%CC%81voro)
>
> Elemento compositivo que significa "que come, que se alimenta de".

Una primera palabra cuyo significado concuerda parcialmente con el término buscado sería *herbívoro*:

> [**herbívoro, ra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KBY2Su7)
>
> Del lat. *herba* 'hierba' y *‒́voro*.
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de un animal: Que se alimenta de vegetales, y más especialmente de hierbas

Pero ya que este término hace énfasis en las hierbas, mi propuesta es usar una palabra en latín para vegetal + el sufijo *‒́voro*.

Una de las opciones que me da el traductor de google para la palabra vegetal en latín es *vegetabili*.

Mi propuesta es entonces:

**Vegetabilívoro**: Que se alimenta de vegetales.

Answer (score 7):

Creo que no es necesario inventar un nuevo término cuando en español hay al menos dos palabras para designar a quien solo come vegetales.

La primera palabra es **herbívoro**.

En zoología ya se distinguen tres grupos de animales dependiendo de su dieta: [herbívoros](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KBY2Su7), [carnívoros](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7clktQp) y [omnívoros](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R3CMkiN).

Un herbívoro es un animal que se alimenta exclusivamente de plantas y no de carne ([ref](https://www.portaleducativo.net/cuarto-basico/623/Animales-carnivoros-herbivoros-omnivoros)), que es exactamente lo que hoy llamamos un vegetariano.

[image: Clasificación según alimentación]

Los humanos pertenecemos al último grupo, por comer de todo, pero si dejamos de comer carne nos devolvemos al primero, al cual pertenecen por ejemplo los gorilas.

La segunda opción es el término **[fitófago](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I1FW4uc)** aunque suena un poco técnico. Sus componentes léxicos son:  *phyton* (vegetal) y *phagein* (comer), más el sufijo -o (agente, el que hace la acción) ([ref](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?fito.fago)).

En la RAE está definida así:

> `De`*`fito-`*`y`*`‒́fago`*`.`
>   1. adj. Que se alimenta de materias vegetales. U. t. c. s.

Comment: Tienes razón, sin embargo en inglés también existe _herbivorous_ y aun así inventaron un término para aplicar a personas y no a animales. A fin de cuentas, una persona vegetariana lo es por voluntad propia, y no por ello deja de ser omnívora. Su cuerpo sigue teniendo la capacidad de comer de todo aunque no la ejerza. Los animales herbívoros lo son porque no tienen otro remedio.

Comment: Pero los humanos vegetarianos siguen siendo animales omnivoros. Me parece que _herbívoro_ se refiere a una característica de la especie (tipo de sistema digestivo, necesidades metabólicas, nicho ecológico, etc.), mientras que _vegetariano_ se refiere a un hábito del individuo.

Comment: @Charlie tu comentario no va en contra de lo que digo. Si por voluntad propia te quieres devolver del 3er grupo al primero, por voluntad propia te conviertes de omnívoro en herbívoro o fitófago. :-) Lo que digo es que no hay que inventar lo que ya existe.

Comment: @Rodrigo tu comentario hace que se me ocurra que también se pueden usar palabras relacionadas con "-filo" como **fitófilo**.

Comment: ¿fitofagófilo...? ¿fitofagético?

Answer (score 6):

La entrada más antigua en el DLE de vegetariano es en la edición de **1914** e indica un origen **francés** (aunque la edición actual indica un origen **inglés**):

> **Vegetariano, na.** (Del fr. *vegetariene.*) adj. Dícese de la persona que se alimenta exclusivamente de vegetales o de sustancias de origen vegetal ...

Por otro lado, en diccionarios anteriores encontramos términos más antiguos relacionados:

- Zerolo (1895):

  > **Vegetalismo.** m. Alimento exclusivo de vegetales.
  >   **Vegetalista.** adj. y s. FITÓFAGO
- Dominguez (1853):

  > **Fitífago, ga.** adj. Zool. Que se alimenta de vejetales. [*sic*]
  >   **Fitófago, ga.** adj. Zool. Que se alimenta de plantas.

Por tanto, antes de que "vegetariano" entrara en el DLE, en español ya ya se utilizaban *vegetalismo*, *vegetalista*, *fitífago* y *fitófago* para describir a los que se alimentan de vegetales y/o plantas (aunque no queda claro si se refieren a animales o a personas).